# Unable web wizard

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, installation, web-setup-wizard

I downloaded my Quickinstall theme, but nothing works as well.
The web installation wizard does not work. I need help installing my theme.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Run the below command in the command line:**

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://localhost/mag24/" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="mag24" --db-user="root" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="admin@admin.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --language="en_US" --currency="INR" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin"
```

Comment: The Web Setup Wizard got removed with 2.4.0:
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/tools.html